# Roles and Hierarchies in SSAS

Tags: security, ssas, mdx, dimensions

I'm having an issue with security on an Analysis Services cube.

I have a dimension, that I need to restrict access to, based on a number of secured fields.

The dimension (Animals, for example) has 5 attributes including :

- Id
- Name
- Gender   (Secured Field)
- Food
- Eye Colour

I need to be able to create hierarchies on this, as :

- Gender -> Id
- Food -> Id
- Eye Colour -> Id

There will be two roles on this Cube, one with access to everything, and one with no access to Id's when using secured fields. However, if the user is filtering by Secured fields, they can see totals against the secured field.

So, if querying against Gender, they would see 20 Male and 20 Female, but wouldn't be able to see the Id's of the 20 Males. A secured user would be able to see the 20 Id's though.

Is this possible, and if so, how would you prevent bypassing the security by filtering on Gender = Male and adding another non-secured hierarchy into the query (such as Eye Colour -> Id) to get the Id's that way ?

Thanks for your time